# Python scraper advice

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, beautifulsoup

I have been working on a scraper for a little while now, and have come very close to getting it to run as intended. My code as follows:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Crawls main site to get a list of city URLs
def getCityLinks():
    city_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.prodigy-living.co.uk/') # Enter url here 
    city_soup = BeautifulSoup(city_sauce, 'html.parser')
    the_city_links = []

    for city in city_soup.findAll('div', class_="city-location-menu"):
        for a in city.findAll('a', href=True, text=True):
            the_city_links.append('https://www.prodigy-living.co.uk/' + a['href'])
    return the_city_links

# Crawls each of the city web pages to get a list of unit URLs
def getUnitLinks():
    getCityLinks()
    for the_city_links in getCityLinks():
        unit_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_city_links)
        unit_soup = BeautifulSoup(unit_sauce, 'html.parser')
        for unit_href in unit_soup.findAll('a', class_="btn white-green icon-right-open-big", href=True):
            yield('the_url' + unit_href['href'])

the_unit_links = []
for link in getUnitLinks():
    the_unit_links.append(link)

# Soups returns all of the html for the items in the_unit_links


def soups():
    for the_links in the_unit_links:
        try:
            sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_links)
            for things in sauce:
                soup_maker = BeautifulSoup(things, 'html.parser')
                yield(soup_maker)
        except:
            print('Invalid url')

# Below scrapes property name, room type and room price

def getPropNames(soup):
    try:
        for propName in soup.findAll('div', class_="property-cta"):
            for h1 in propName.findAll('h1'):
                print(h1.text)
    except:
        print('Name not found')

def getPrice(soup):
    try:
        for price in soup.findAll('p', class_="room-price"):
            print(price.text)
    except:
        print('Price not found')


def getRoom(soup):
    try:
        for theRoom in soup.findAll('div', class_="featured-item-inner"):
            for h5 in theRoom.findAll('h5'):
                print(h5.text)
    except:
        print('Room not found')

for soup in soups():
    getPropNames(soup)
    getPrice(soup)
    getRoom(soup)
```

When I run this, it returns all the prices for all the urls picked up. However, I does not return the names or the rooms and I am not really sure why. I would really appreciate any pointers on this, or ways to improve my code - been learning Python for a few months now!

Comment: for web crawling in python, I would highly recommend using [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org)

Comment: What does it return instead?

Comment: also, this totally depends on the site you are crawling, and without sharing that information, we can't know if what you are parsing is correct.

Comment: @ryugie it returns only the prices

Comment: Sorry, I have amended the question if you would'nt mind having a look? @ryugie

Comment: @eLRuLL - added the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the links you are scraping will in the end redirect you to another website, in which case your scraping functions will not be useful! 
For instance, the link for a room in Birmingham is redirecting you to another website.

Also, be careful in your usage of the `find` and `find_all` methods in BS. The first returns only one tag (as when you want one property name) while `find_all()` will return a list allowing you to get,  for instance, multiple room prices and types.

Anyway, I have simplified a bit your code and this is how I have come across your issue. Maybe you would like to get some inspiration from that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "https://www.prodigy-living.co.uk/"

# Getting individual cities url
re = requests.get(main_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
city_tags = soup.find("div", class_ = "footer-city-nav") # Bottom page not loaded dynamycally
cities_links = [main_url+tag["href"] for tag in city_tags.find_all("a")] # Links to cities


# Getting the individual links to the apts
indiv_apts = []

for link in cities_links[0:4]:
    print "At link: ", link
    re = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
    links_tags = soup.find_all("a", class_ = "btn white-green icon-right-open-big")

    for url in links_tags:
        indiv_apts.append(main_url+url.get("href"))

# Now defining your functions
def GetName(tag):
    print tag.find("h1").get_text()

def GetType_Price(tags_list):
    for tag in tags_list:
        print tag.find("h5").get_text()
        print tag.find("p", class_ = "room-price").get_text()

# Now scraping teach of the apts - name, price, room.
for link in indiv_apts[0:2]:
    print "At link: ", link
    re = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
    property_tag = soup.find("div", class_ = "property-cta")
    rooms_tags = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "featured-item")
    GetName(property_tag)
    GetType_Price(rooms_tags)
```

You will see that right at the second element of the lis, you will get an `AttributeError` as you are not on your website page anymore. Indeed:

```
>>> print indiv_apts[1]
https://www.prodigy-living.co.uk/http://www.iqstudentaccommodation.com/student-accommodation/birmingham/penworks-house?utm_source=prodigylivingwebsite&utm_campaign=birminghampagepenworksbutton&utm_medium=referral # You will not scrape the expected link right at the beginning
```

Next time come with a precise problem to solve, or in another case just take a look at the code review section.

On `find` and `find_all`: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all

Finally, I think it also answers your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506033/urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11001-getaddrinfo-failed

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't anticipate someone would rewrite it, but this works perfectly! I've added in a `try` and `except` and it runs as intended.

Comment: Happy to help :) I always briefly check up whats in a list before iterating on it

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed that some of the links where redirecting to another site before posting. I want to figure a way to add those to a separate list. Thank you again!